# How to Acces all Images and Videos stored on SD-Card in Blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

There is a problem in getting all images and Videos stored on SD-Card in Blackberry, kindly help me that how can i access these. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is this a programming question, or are you just trying to open the files in the UI?  If it's a programming question, show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 2):

My Problem has been resolved by taking a look on FileExplorerDemo in the Blackberrry JDE samples.